# SVG z-order with opacity < 1

Tags: svg, opacity, z-order

I'm constructing an SVG image (tree map, with ellipses for nodes) where I want to connect the ellipses with lines, but I want the lines to begin at the *edges* of the ellipses. Since calculating where the edges fall and starting or ending the lines exactly there is very difficult, I'm drawing the lines from the centers of the ellipses and looking for a way to have the ellipse superimposed on the line, so that it masks out the overlapping part, giving the appearance of having the lines begin only at the edge of the ellipse. Because SVG implements z-order through element order, if I create the connecting lines first and then the ellipses, that works, except that ...

... I want the ellipses to be blue or red with fill-opacity="0.15", but when I do that, the lines show through. It makes sense, of course, that something of low opacity can't fully mask the thing it covers, but I'm having trouble figuring how I can get the effect I want. I found one working solution: for each ellipse that I want, I create first an ellipse of the same size and position with a white fill and opacity of 1, and that masks the connecting line fully where they overlap. I then superimpose on the white ellipse the ellipse I really want to render, with the blue or red fill and opacity of 0.15. That looks the way I want it to look, but it feels kludgy. Is there a graceful solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: That sounds kludgy. Why do you need a semi transparent background? Do you need other elements or background to show through your nodes? Or you just need the color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipping or masking.

Draw the lines the whole way, but clip them to everything except the ellipses.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the color after it has rendered the `fill-opacity` against a white background.

Take a screenshot of your SVG, open it in a graphics editing program such as Photoshop, use the eyedropper tool to inspect the rendered color and copy the hex value. Then use it as a fill color with `fill-opacity="1"`